Pandas dataframe dtype as Category is not maintained after adding data
I know the categories upfront. Hence, i want to create a dataframe and keep adding data to it as and when i consume new messages.
I am able to create dataframe and add data. The problem that i am facing is that the dtype changes as soon as the data is added to the dataframe. The dtype is not being preserved.
The options that i tried are:
cols = ['picture1', 'picture2', 'picture3']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df[cols] = df[cols].astype('category')
df.info() # Here the dtype is category
df.loc[0] = ['GOOD', 'BAD', 'UGLY']
df.info() # Here dtype changes to object

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'picture1': pd.Categorical([],categories=['GOOD', 'GOOD1'],),
                    'picture2': pd.Categorical([],categories=['BAD', 'BAD1'],),
                    'picture3': pd.Categorical([],categories=['UGLY', 'UGLY1'],)
                   })
df1.info() # Here the dtype is category
df1.loc[0] = ['GOOD', 'BAD', 'UGLY']
df1.info() # Here dtype changes to object

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'picture1': pd.Series(['GOOD'], dtype="category"),
                   'picture2': pd.Series(['BAD'], dtype="category"),
                   'picture3': pd.Series(['UGLY'], dtype="category")
                   })
df2.info() # Here the dtype is category
df2['picture1'] = df2['picture1'].cat.add_categories(['GOOD1'])
df2['picture2'] = df2['picture2'].cat.add_categories(['BAD1'])
df2['picture3'] = df2['picture2'].cat.add_categories(['UGLY1'])
df2.loc[1] = ['GOOD1', 'BAD1', 'UGLY1']
df2.info() # Here dtype changes to object

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'picture1': pd.Series(dtype="category"),
                   'picture2': pd.Series(dtype="category"),
                   'picture3': pd.Series(dtype="category")
                   })
df3.info() # Here the dtype is category
df3['picture1'] = df3['picture1'].cat.set_categories(['GOOD', 'GOOD1'])
df3['picture2'] = df3['picture2'].cat.add_categories(['BAD', 'BAD1'])
df3['picture3'] = df3['picture2'].cat.add_categories(['UGLY', 'UGLY1'])
df3.loc[0] = ['GOOD', 'BAD', 'UGLY']
df3.info() # Here dtype changes to object

How to ensure that the dtype of certain columns stays as category even after data is inserted?
Thanks

You can pass the data as pd.Series where you define the datatype.
df.loc[0] = pd.Series(['GOOD', 'BAD', 'UGLY'], dtype='category')
